# how can i pass the value of array variable populated in scriplets of jsp code to a combobox?

Tags: jsp, netbeans

How can i pass the value of array variable populated in scriplets of jsp code to a combobox?
combobox is defined in  of the same code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<c:for` [jstl tag](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) to iterate over the array and set the combo with its values.